# Why is the following map from $S^1$ to $S^2$ null-homotopic

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-topology

I am reading the following proof from hatcher. There is a certain point I don't understand. Why is the map given by $\eta : S^1 \to S^2$ null-homotopic in $S^2$?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The $2$-sphere $S^2$ is simply connected (e.g. by van Kampen's theorem), hence *any* map $S^1 \to S^2$ is nullhomotopic. You can also write down an explicit nullhomotopy for $\eta$ if you want: $\eta$ circles the equator, you can "push it" towards the north pole (circling smaller and smaller circles parallel to the equator), and at the end you get a constant map. More concretely, let:
$$\eta_t(s) = ((1-t^2) \cos(2\pi s), (1-t^2) \sin(2 \pi s), t).$$
Then $\eta_0(s) = \eta(s)$ and $\eta_1(s) = (0,0,1)$ for all $s$. You can also massage this into a homotopy with fixed endpoints, if you are so inclined.

Comment: Just quick question would the $\eta_t(s)$ homotopy work as well if you do $\eta_t(s) = ((1 - t)cos(2\pi s),(1 - t)sin(2\pi s),t)$?

Comment: @TheKEMO Your $\eta_t(s)$ does not belong to $S^2$.

Comment: I see. I understand now.

Comment: how to fix the endpoints?